# Advice on fingering and hand position

Tags: practice, learning, fingering, digital-piano, hand-independence

I am practicing **left** hand of the following peice on piano. It needs to be played relatively fast with fingers spanned over an octave, involving D3, G3, B3b, D4. Any advice on how to position my hand for best performance?

[image]

Comment: How big are your hands? I'd give you different advice if you can't hold down a ninth with one hand, for instance.

Comment: I can reach a ninth, but with difficulty. I am comfortable playing an octave.

Comment: `B3#` ? - in the score example there is a B-flat used, shouldn't it be `B3b`?

Comment: @nath Oh yeah, my bad. Changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a fingering like this:

[image]

**Update:**

- in terms of hand position, you will have some kind of rotation, bending when playing in this octave some kind of `)` shape from you forearm to your fifth finger tip.
- I would not play this with flat fingers, since it should be played fast I would keep my fingers as round as possible.
- the vertical position I would have my fifth finger on the `D3` right in the first section between C# and D#, the third finger rather towards the end of `G3` the second finger almost in the middle of `B3b` and the first finger on `D4` rather at the front bit of the key, definitely not between the black keys.

Comment: How do you position you hand itself. Would you try to bend your finger, and form your hand like a cup. Or would you do it almost straightened hand. I noticed that flat hand and fingers are more comfortable in this particular case.

Comment: @SaraWinslet I updated my answer truing to describe hand, finger position and shapes.

Comment: Link provided in comment is dead.

Comment: @Aaron I removed the obsolete post. Thanks again!